# Getting an error from pyffmpeg when running as a submodule

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

I'm working on building an API using `pyffmpeg` and `pytube` to download YouTube videos and convert them to .wav files, synced up with some LED animations. I'm importing `pyffmpeg` in a submodule, which is then imported by yet another submodule. I'm getting the following error when I run the script (both from my entire package, and in the Python shell directly, and on two different devices with two different OSes):

This is the error I get from the shell on my MacBook:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyffmpeg/__init__.py", line 163, in convert
    raise Exception(self.error)
Exception
```

And this is the error I get on my Raspberry Pi when I run the full program:

```
  File "/path/to/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pyffmpeg/__init__.py", line 154, in convert
    if 'Output #0' not in stderr:
                          ^^^^^^
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'stderr' where it is not associated with a value
```

I've tracked down the relevant code in the `__init__.py` file of `pyffmpeg`, but I'm not sure how to fix the problem.

```py
        if 'Output #0' not in stderr:
            lines = stderr.splitlines()
            if len(lines) > 0:
                self.error = lines[-1]
            else:
                self.error = ""

            if self.enable_log:
                self.logger.error(self.error)
            raise Exception(self.error)
        else:
            self.error = ''
            if self.enable_log:
                self.logger.info('Conversion Done')
        return out
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: In the [try/except](https://github.com/deuteronomy-works/pyffmpeg/blob/2b5a4a70025f79fa09b089e7bba35f7a6e3036cc/pyffmpeg/__init__.py#L142) above the section you quoted, it looks like an exception while starting the process can cause the `stderr` variable to be undefined. Unfortunately, due to the library author's use of [bare except](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except), that's all I can tell.

Comment: You might want to try [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python). It's a very similar library, but it's much more popular and therefore probably easier to find information about errors such as this.